# Activate menu item with preprocess_page function

Tags: routes, theming

Hi my international friends!

I work in Drupal 7.38.

If the current page belongs to a specific content type, I want to activate a specific menu item.
By ***to activate a specific menu item*** I mean that this menu item has the class ***active***.

I try to do this with **preprocess_page()** function within template.php. It does not work **:(**.

Here is the code.

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if( !empty($vars['node']) ) {
    switch ( $vars['node']->type ) {
      case 'machine_name_my_content_type':
        menu_tree_set_path('machine_name_menu','path_menu_item');
        break;
      default:
        menu_tree_set_path('machine_name_menu','path_menu_item');
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried a variation. Instead of putting:

```
menu_tree_set_path ('machine_name_menu' 'path_menu_item')
```

I put `menu_set_active_item ('path_menu_item')`

**Nothing works!**

Can you help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the [Menu position module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_position)

Comment: I installed [Custom Active Menu Item](https://www.drupal.org/project/cami) module. It works fine! But I want to learn how to do it with PHP! Thank you.